Which pins are used for I2C and SPI in ESP32-S3?
I am using ESP32-S3-WROOM-1-N16R2 Controller in my design. I want to connect Sensor with this module which has both I2C and SPI Communication pins. I gone through the datasheet for controller, but i didn't find particular pins for I2C and SPI Communication. Can anyone explain?
Datasheet Link: https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-s3-wroom-1_wroom-1u_datasheet_en.pdf

Perhaps link to the data sheet you are reading, and then someone can explain.

Esp32 has the ability to map any peripheral to just about any pin so you decide what pins you use.

@Kartman that is true, but there is limitation on clock frequency for SPI if you dont use specific pins.

These kind of information is usually in the SoC datasheet, not the board one. In this case it's this datasheet https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-s3_datasheet_en.pdf (it is also linked from the board datasheet)
In this case it seems to be pins 5-6-7-8 when set with RTC function 3. There's a handy table at the end with all the pins and their functions.
